# Installing "Edit Line Item" extension CiviDiscount permission error

Tags: extension, cividiscount, refund

Upon installing "Edit Line Item" extension with CiviDiscount already installed I get this error:

> Some modules define permissions but the CMS cannot store them;
>   cividiscount

Any advice?